# Group and count elements and sort them by column outside the group by clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have `links` table with columns `url` and `created_at`, for example:

```
url      |  created_at
ex2.com  |  2
ex1.com  |  3
ex2.com  |  1
ex1.com  |  4
ex3.com  |  5
```

I'd like to group it by url, count this urls and sort by url_count and created_at of the first url in group, so result would be:

```
url      |  url_count
ex2.com  |  2
ex1.com  |  2
ex3.com  |  1
```

I do `Link.select(:url).group(:url).order('count_url DESC').count` and now  I need only sort by created_at but I lost it's value in this query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple columns in `Model.select` e.g.:

```
Link.select("url, created_at, count(*) as count_url").group("url").order("created_at")
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: I tried something like this, but get an error : `PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "links.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: Of course. Try ``max(created_at) as created_at``. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/tutorial-agg.html

Answer (score 0):

with window function I would :

```
select distinct url,count(url) over (partition by url) from a
-------------------
url      |  url_count
ex2.com  |  2
ex1.com  |  2
ex3.com  |  1
```

If you can translate this to ruby...